# Python Pandas read_excel() module not found

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to use pandas.read_excel() to import an .xlsx file using this basic script

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_excel("crypt_db.xlsx", "sheet1")
```

and I get a module ('read_excel') not found error. Could I get some help on this?

My pandas is updated to the latest version.

Thank you for your help

Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_excel'
```

Comment: please post a full traceback of your error

Comment: until you give is a fuller traceback not much anyone can do,, fwiw you do need to specify the "sheet1" as well read_excel requires two arguments.. I just checked my install and it seems fine. x = pd.read_excel("crypt_db.xlsx", "sheet1")

Comment: full traceback posted with xlrd already installed!

Comment: What output do you get when you just enter `pd` in the console?

Comment: Not that it matters much now, but this is one reason why you should post the actual traceback instead of describing it: you said you had a "module not found error", which isn't really a thing.  Instead you have an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @joris here's the output that I get when I enter in 'pd' into the console
<module 'pandas' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/__init__.pyc'>

Comment: And what do you get for `pd.__version__`? Maybe it is not using an updated pandas.

Comment: i get 0.7.0 which is strange because using 'apt-get install python-pandas' says 'python-pandas is already the newest version.'

Comment: Fixed with 'pip install --upgrade pandas'

Answer (score 4):

Install package `xlrd`:

```
pip install xlrd
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, xlrd is already installed on my system

Answer (score 1):

`sheet1` is the Excel table sheet1's true name? if not,maybe you can try by sheet1's true name or use the sheet1's index like,

```
x = pd.read_excel("crypt_db.xlsx", 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the message when upgrading pandas, but `xlrd` was not updated. Run this:

```
pip install --upgrade xlrd
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command in cmd:

```
  pip install openpyxl
```

> ***openpyxl***  is a Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm/xltx/xltm files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Even though I already had xlrd installed, I still experienced the same problem as OG. Installing openpyxl resolved the problem, though (no code change required).

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
#import player regular season
df = pd.read_excel ("Player-Data-Set/NBA-Player-Statistics-season.xlsx", [0,1,2,3,4])
```

Thank you Chanda Korat your post put me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel' (most likely due to a circular import)

I faced a similar problem

it got solved when I renamed org.py to organization.py

There are references to packages
org.python.core

org.py is being read as package hence the problem...

please be aware when naming python files.